# Как парсить подгружаемые данные с сайта?

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, requests, beautiful-soup

Некоторая часть  `HTML`-кода страницы **динамически подгружается** *GET-запросом* через скрипты `JS`, во вкладке *Network* это выглядит примерно так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
На одном из связанных вопросов видел модуль `selenium`, в частности его класс `webdriver` (`from selenium import webdriver`), помогающий перехватить все динамически загружаемые части кода.
Но страниц этого сайта, содержимое которых также надо спарсить, более чем 25.000, так что подобный, в данной ситуации, *костыль*, замедлит парсинг на добрых пару часов. В связи с этим задаю вопрос: как перехватить только некоторые загружаемые на сайт данные,  по возможности используя, модуль `requests`?

Comment: Ну, просто из той же вкладки Network вытащить все интересующие ссылки и передать их в модуль requests?

Comment: @andreymal уж не знаю, что за магия, но запрос ссылается на эту же страницу

Comment: Значит в той же вкладке Network изучайте, чем запрос данных по этой ссылке отличается от просто открытия страницы по этой ссылке

Comment: либо через браузер исследуете сайт, ищете ссылки на api и тянете данные с них, либо через селениум - с помощью js хуков получаете данные